# What identifier is used by multipath to determine the same block devices?

Tags: block-device, iscsi, multipath-storage

In my application I want to multipath different devices, both local and iSCSI or FC exported. However, I fail to google the documentation that would clearly explain the mechanism of decision that block devices are the same by `multipath` util.

There is a dozen of different unique identifiers of block devices (serial number, UUID on host/target/LUN levels, WWN, WWID, IQN, etc.). Which of them can be used to multipath devices? Is it possible to combine block devices exported via two protocols (say, SAS and iSCSI)?